# How to make a phone number clickable in a SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services

I am writing a SSRS report that includes a list of names and their phone numbers. I was wondering if it was possible to make the phone numbers that appear in the report tablix clickable so that they can be skyped by the user - similar to how URLs can be.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your textbox and on placeholder properties and set it to HTML
[image]

Set your textbox expression to an html link like the expression below

```
="<a href='tel:123-456-7890'>123-456-7890</a>"
```

This will create a telephone link.
[image]

In order to test the link, you have to deploy the report and test it through a browser

Comment: Thanks a lot niktrs.
For anyone doing this using a field value (eg TelephoneNumber), the syntax is:
="<a href='tel:" + Fields!TelephoneNumber.Value + "'>" + Fields!TelephoneNumber.Value + "</a>"